# stream video from rtsp with frame rate of 1 fps

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

i am trying to stream only one frame per second from rtsp , I am using ffmpeg with following command

> ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp:/XXXXX -q:v 1 -vf fps=fps=1 -f mpegts udp://Y.Y.Y.Y:ZZ

but i receive higher rate than 1 fps.

P.S
Capturing frame in 1 fps and saving it in any other method (not images) will fix the problem also

Answer (score 0):

Use the realtime filter.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp:/XXXXX -q:v 1 -vf fps=1,realtime -f mpegts udp://Y.Y.Y.Y:ZZ
```

If you have audio, you will need to add `-af arealtime`.